# gulp-sourcemaps outputs incorrect sources in .css.map

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my configuration of gulp and gulp-sourcemaps. My `main.css` and `main.css.map` are compiled, yet I get incorrect sources:

```
{"version":3,"file":"main.css","sources":["/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css" [...] etc
```

It never displays anything other than `main.css` as a source. When I inspect via the browser and click on the source it shows me the **last imported file in SCSS.**

This is my Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.sass.src)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({largeFile: true}))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError ))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.sass.dest));
});
```

My `config.sass.src` is `assets/sass/**/*.{sass,scss}`

I also had some `autoprefixer` pipes and `cssnano` but I have commented all the extra things out and tried to run that as well, alas, same stuff.

Here is a minimal example of my SCSS:

`main.scss`:

```
@import "components/buttons";
```

`components/_buttons.scss`:

```
button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

This outputs the following in the css.map:

```
{"version":3,"file":"main.css","sources":["/assets/sass/main.css","/assets/sass/main.css"],"sourcesContent":["@import \"components/buttons\";","button {\n    padding: 10px;\n    background: black;\n    color: white;\n    border: 0;\n    border-radius: 0;\n}"],"mappings":"ACAA,AAAA,MAAM,CAAC;EACH,OAAO,EAAE,IAAK;EACd,UAAU,EAAE,KAAM;EAClB,KAAK,EAAE,KAAM;EACb,MAAM,EAAE,CAAE;EACV,aAAa,EAAE,CAAE,GACpB","names":[]}
```

Using:

- gulp 3.9.1
- gulp-sass 2.3.2
- gulp-sourcemaps 1.10.0

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with your task. You'd have to provide a minimal SASS/SCSS file that reproduces the problem to have any chance of figuring this out.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung done! I also added what my `config.sass.src` is, I thought the issue may be that I am using every scss/sass file as the source so I changed it to the path of `main.scss` and that did build the css, but the sourcemaps are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [a bug](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/270) in the version of `gulp-sourcemaps` that you're using.

Updating from `1.10.0` to `1.10.1` should fix the issue:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-sourcemaps
```

Comment: I was just about to walk out of the door and go home, this worked! (I use yarn though but same principle). Where did you find this? I have searched for at least two hours using [terms like this](http://i.imgur.com/N7pq6hQ.png) and that's only search terms when I knew it was something to do with gulp-sourcemaps. In any case, thanks a bunch! All I need to do now is point to the correct source location but I can probably figure that one out myself tomorrow ;)

Comment: Well, after I was able to reproduce the problem with the info in your question the only explanation I could think of was a bug in `gulp-sourcemaps`. Tried upgrading the plugin and when that fixed it I went looking at [the recent commits](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/commits/v1.10.1) where [issue #270](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/issues/270) was linked.